# How do I after in a slide when it is hidden?

Tags: powerpoint

I have inserted a video in a slide and set it to hide when it isn't playing. How do I play the video after I have shown the audience the slide?

Comment: Show the video on the next slide?

Comment: Is there any way I can show the text and the video on the same slide? I know it's autistic but...